# Create app for Windows Mobile 6 (and above)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6

What IDE (and version) and it components should I use to build that app? For now I write in C# so that will be cool if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use for wm:
VS 2008 pro, Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1 (x64), Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK. Im not sure about Davide Piras' answer above. I have never heard that anyone managed to install WM 6 project profiles in any VS above 2008 version. Beside v2008, i also have VS2012 installed and it doesnt register any MW project from Mobile SDK 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

in the past i used Visual Studio .NET 2005 with the .NET compact Framework, that allows you to build apps for windows mobile 6.

mind that there is no above, Windows Phone ( 8 or 10 ) is a completely different beast than Windows Mobile 6 and app development for Windows Phone is still done in .NET but I don't think you have code or binary compatibility between Windows Mobile and Windows Phone.

Comment: You mean 2005 version?

Comment: The only officially supported MS VS for Windows Mobile 6 and other Windows CE 5 or 6 based devices and WEC7 is Visual Studio 2008! Eveything else is a hack except for other commercial RAD tool designed for Windows Mobile/Embedded Handheld (ie WinDev, if you like).

Comment: yes sorry i meant VS 2005 as i used back then! Sorry